# Logic App processed/error: decryption-failed Error: An error occurred when decrypting an AS2 message

Tags: azure-logic-apps, b2b

I have a logic app to receive x12 messages over AS2. The messags received are signed and encrypted.

The AS2 decode connector is successful but has failed MDN  status as below.

```
 "isFailedMessage": true,"dispositionType</g>":"processed/error: decryption-failed Error: An error occurred when decrypting an AS2 message."
```

As for as I know , I have done all the right configurations for AS2 agreement receiver.  Even  tried to not override the properties and still see the same issue.

I have a couple of questions.

1> When I used B2B management solution in diagnostic logs, there was no additional information which can help me to diagnose the issue. There is only one entry showing the error information.  How can find more on what exactly went wrong at AS2-Decode connector side?

2> Can you also help me why this issue could be occurring

The same flow works fine without encryption enabled(source obviously need to send an unencrypted as2 message).

Thanks

Srinivasa mahendrakar

Answer (score 1):

I needed to encode the content as @base64ToBinary message before posting to a receiving logic app. After this issue seems to be sorted out.

```
"Response": {
   "inputs": {
   "body": "@base64ToBinary(body('Decode_AS2_message')?['OutgoingMDN']?['Content'])",
   "headers": "@body('Decode_AS2_message')?['OutgoingMDN']?['OutboundHeaders']",
   "statusCode": 200
},
```

I found solution here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-enterprise-integration-b2b-list-errors-solutions